# python tab separated file parsing problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

From mysql I am generating a tab-separated output file using [outfile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html). I then use python to load the tsv and process it. I feel like I'm missing something, but I cannot figure out how to get `csv.reader` to accept data where quoted fields can contain `\t` tabs, `\n` newlines, `\r` carriage returns, etc. The `csv.reader` keeps breaking the rows on **all** newline characters, not just the `\n` newline characters outside of my quoted fields.

### Settings:

```
with open('/path/to/file.tsv', 'rbU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(
        f,
        delimiter='\t',
        lineterminator='\n',
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL
    )
    for line in reader:
        #  do something
```

### Example:

In the example below, `\r` is an actual carriage return, `\n` is an actual newline, and `\N` is what mysql is outputting for a null value.

```
"4256996"   "test@gmail.com"    "Y  "   "98230\r"   "2012-07-10T12:00:00"   "some  location"    \N  \N  "false" "aaa"   "another-field" "true"  1
```

The resulting output:

```
['4256996', 'test@gmail.com', 'Y\t', '98230'], ['2012-07-10T12:00:00', 'some  location', '\\N', '\\N', 'false', 'aaa', 'another-field', 'true', '1']
```

Is there a way to get the `csv.reader` to read this input data properly, or is this some sort of limitation with the `csv.reader` object?

Note: If you try to replicate this, make sure you replace `\r` with an actual carriage return, `\n` with an actual newline, etc.

Comment: How are you opening the file? Please include the `open()` call and the way you set up the reader.

Comment: @MartijnPieters updated it with a more explicit example

Comment: Why the `'rbU'` mode? Binary mode doesn't do universal line endings, universal line endings assumes text mode instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open your file in *binary mode only*. By adding in `'U'` (universal newline mode) you are instead instructing Python to replace any `\r` with `\n`.

```
with open('/path/to/file.tsv', 'rb') as f:
```

Once reading *just* binary data your sample input works:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> sample = BytesIO('''\
... "4256996"\t"test@gmail.com"\t"Y  "\t"98230\r"\t"2012-07-10T12:00:00"\t"some  location"\t\\N\t\\N\t"false"\t"aaa"\t"another-field"\t"true"\t1\r\n''')
>>> sample.readline()
'"4256996"\t"test@gmail.com"\t"Y  "\t"98230\r"\t"2012-07-10T12:00:00"\t"some  location"\t\\N\t\\N\t"false"\t"aaa"\t"another-field"\t"true"\t1\r\n'
>>> sample.seek(0)
0L
>>> reader = csv.reader(sample, delimiter='\t',
...         lineterminator='\n',
...         quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL
...     )
>>> next(reader)
['4256996', 'test@gmail.com', 'Y  ', '98230\r', '2012-07-10T12:00:00', 'some  location', '\\N', '\\N', 'false', 'aaa', 'another-field', 'true', '1']
```

To illustrate, reading a line with the `U` mode set Python reads the data incorrectly:

```
>>> sample.seek(0)
0L
>>> open('/tmp/test.csv', 'wb').write(sample.read())
>>> f = open('/tmp/test.csv', 'rbU')
>>> f.readline()
'"4256996"\t"test@gmail.com"\t"Y  "\t"98230\n'
>>> f = open('/tmp/test.csv', 'rb')
>>> f.readline()
'"4256996"\t"test@gmail.com"\t"Y  "\t"98230\r"\t"2012-07-10T12:00:00"\t"some  location"\t\\N\t\\N\t"false"\t"aaa"\t"another-field"\t"true"\t1\r\n'
```

Comment: Argghhh! Thank you! I added the ``b`` option at the same time I added the ``U`` option and missed that...